# Number of fixed points converges to poisson distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, permutations, poisson-distribution, fixed-points

I am currently studying the concept of convergence in distribution in probability theory.

We have the permutation $\tau : \{1,\dots,n\} \to \{1,\dots,n\}$.
Let $\tau_n$ be a random permutation chosen uniformly random from all $n!$ possible permutations.

We let $X_n$ be the number of fixed points of $\tau_n$.

I want to show that  $\lim_{n\to\infty} F_{X_n} = F_X$ where $X$ ~ $\text{Poi}(1)$.

I am given a hint that I can explain that it is enough to show that $P(X_n = j) \to \frac{1}{ej!}$ for any fixed $j$. 
After that I can use the fact that $P(X_n = 0) \to 1/e$ as $n \to \infty$ (I have already proven this stament) to estimate the number of permutations with exactly j fixed points.

The thing I cannot get my head around is the part where I need to explain that it is enough to show that $P(X_n = j) \to \frac{1}{ej!}$ for any fixed $j$. Can someone clarify this a little for me?

I started with writing out that

$F_{X_n} = P(X_n \leq j) = P(X_n = 0) + P(X_n = 1) + \dots + P(X_n = j)$

But everything I tried after that didn't really make things clearer for me..

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2465803/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate $P\left(X_n=j\right)$, you need to calculate the amount of permutations $\tau_n:\{1,...,n\}\longrightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ with j fixed points.

If we were to construct such a permutation we'd have $binomial(n,j)=\frac{n!}{\left(n-j\right)! j!}$ possibilities to choose j fixed points. 
Now we have n-j ponints left, to construct permutations without fixed points. 
Following the wikipedia aricle about [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), there are \begin{align}
\left(n-j\right)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k!} 
\end{align}
permutations $\tau_{n-j}:\{1,...,n-j\}\longrightarrow \{1,...,n-j\}$ **without** fixed points.

Thus there are $\frac{n!}{\left(n-j\right)! j!} \left(n-j\right)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k!} $ permutations with exactly $j$ fixed points.

Overall there are $n!$ permutations, therefore 
\begin{align}
    P\left(X_n=j\right)&= \frac{\frac{n!}{\left(n-j\right)! j!} \left(n-j\right)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k!} }{n!} \\
&= 
\frac{1}{j!} \sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\frac{\left(-1\right)^k}{k!} \\
&\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{j!} \frac{1}{e}.
\end{align}

In conclusion we see, that 
\begin{align}
   P\left(X_n=j\right) \underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{j! e} =\frac{1^j e^{-1}}{j!},
\end{align}
 which ist the probability density of the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Definition) with parameter $\lambda=1$.
Then 
$\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty }F_{X_n}= F_X$, wehere $X \sim \text{Poi}\left(1\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand your reasoning, however I do not really understand **why** it is sufficient enough to show that $P(X_n = j) \to \frac{1}{ej!}$. Can you maybe corroborate this a bit?

Comment: I edited the answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, I get that haha :D but, I mean this: $F_{X_n} = P(X_n \leq j) = P(X_n = 0) +  P(X_n = 1) +...+ P(X_n = j)$. So I would say that we need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}( P(X_n = 0) +  P(X_n = 1) +...+ P(X_n = j))$.

Why is showing that the limit of $P(X_n = j)$ (i.e. only the last term) converges to a Poisson distribution enough?

Comment: It holds $P\left( X_n = t \right)\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{t!}\frac{1}{e} \forall t\in\{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: But if that relation holds for all $t$, that would imply that
$\\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n \leq j)
 = \lim_{n\to\infty}(P(X_n=0)+P(X_n=1)+ \dots +(X_n=j))
= \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n = 0) +  \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n = 1) + \dots \lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n = j)
 = \frac{1}{e0!} +  \frac{1}{e1!} + \dots +  \frac{1}{ej!}$

which is different from $ \frac{1}{ej!}$. Right?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I could get the fomat right: the word "which" should be on the last line before "is different from".

Comment: That's correct!  So you have $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P\left(X_n\leq j\right)= \frac{1}{e 0!}+\frac{1}{e 1!}+...+\frac{1}{e j!}= P\left(X\leq j\right)=F_X\left(j\right)$, 
where $X\sim \text{Poi}\left(1\right)$. As you wanted.

Comment: Thankyou!! I was thinking stupid, of course the CDF is the sum of the PMF's.