# There's 100 boxes and 100 balls, both labeled. What's the probability that at least one box has a ball with same number?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, derangements

Randomly place 100 balls, labeled from 1 to 100, in the 100 boxes, also labeled. What is the chance that at least one box contains the ball with matching label?

Wouldn't this be a binomial distribution since we have 1 trial of randomly placing one ball in each box and each box has a probability of (1/100) of getting a ball of the same label? If so, then the probability is:

P(x = 2) = (100 choose 1) (1/100)^1 (1-(1/100)^99 = .0037

X ~ Bin(1, 1/100) since there are 100 boxes and each boxes has a probability of 1/100 of getting the ball with the same number.

BUT, when I approximate it using the Poisson variable(lamda = 1), I get :
P(i>= 1) = 1 -P(i=0)
= 1 - e^-1
= .63

What am I missing here? **Shouldn't the approximations be close?**

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: P(at least one) = 1- P(absolutely none);  P(absolutely none)=$\prod P(k$th ball isn't$)=(\frac {99}{100})^{100} \approx 0.366$ so P(at least one)$\approx$ 1- 0.366 = 0.634$.  I don't understand what "P(x = 2) = (100 choose 1) (1/100)^1 (1-(1/100)^99 = .0037" means or why that is supposed to by an answer.

Comment: Oops... okay, my calculation assumed a ball being in the right/wrong box was independent of the other balls and boxes. Still I think you simply have an error in your first calculation.

Comment: I think so too, but the setup and logical is correct for the binomial distribution ?

Comment: The probability of all the balls being *DIFFERENT* by the binomial distribution is ${100\choose 1}(\frac 1{100})^1(1-\frac 1{100})^{99}$ which is equal to $0.37$ and *not* $0.0037$.  So the probability of the balls having at least *one* in place is $1- 0.37 = 0.63$.

Answer (score 2):

This reduces to finding the probability of a given permutation having at least one fixed point (i.e it not being a derangement). [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465803/whats-the-probability-that-a-given-permutation-has-exactly-k-fixed-points) details how to compute the probability of $k$ agreements in labels. The TL;DR of it is:

$$
p = 1 - \sum_{n=0}^{100}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}
$$

which indeed is extremely well-approximated by $1-e^{-1}$.

Comment: I agree, but i'm still trying to understand why they do not approximate to one another.

Comment: "I agree, but i'm still trying to understand why they do not approximate to one another. "  ???? but they *do*!  Moh, just demonstrated that they do.

Comment: I know they do, but I'm trying to see what I did wrong in my binomial calculations. I got .0037 when I did the binomial approximation and .63 for poisson.